# How to put a picture next to the jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I found no topic to talk about this, I apologize if not researched properly. Is there any way to put a picture next to a jquery dialog, as the following image? If yes how?

[image: Dialog]

Comment: I do not understand why this is not an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BwQzs/5/

html:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>A dialog...</p>
</div>
<img style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0; width: 70px;" id="dialogimage" src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/3167619400/f6e8d4a5be06c62a6ea863c3d6dce875.png" />
```

js:

```
    $(function(){
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({

        open: function( event, ui ) {
          $('#dialogimage').css({
              left:$(this).offset().left-75,
              top:$(this).offset().top-46
            });
        },
        drag: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#dialogimage').css({
                left:ui.position.left-70,
                top:ui.position.top,display:'block'
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks that was really it could not do

Comment: One more question, when I show the dialog box, from behind that window it shows the gray background including image that helped me. How do I take this image to gray?

Comment: You can put the image in a container,next another container with absolute position, above the image, with the background-color:gray and opacity somewhere in the middle. Or you can just edit the image into an image editor and make it gray then upload it on the server.